# PostGIS crosstab error code

Tags: postgresql, cross-tabulation

Can anyone tell me why this does not work?

```
SQL error: SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
'select town, rescode, proptype 
FROM "public.windhamCoParcels" 
WHERE rescode = 'C'
   or rescode = 'S'
   or rescode = 'NS'
   or rescode = 'T'
   order by 1,2')
   AS Town(town_name text, Commercial text, in_state text, non_state text, town text);
 returned 0 [ERROR:  syntax error at or near "C"
LINE 5: WHERE rescode = 'C'
```

Comment: It fails because the apostrophe before the `'C'` is closing the string starting at `'select`. You would have to escape it. For things like this, use dollar-quoting (`$$`) in the outer string instead of single quotes

Comment: ... and then, the table is most likely `"public"."windhamCoParcels"`. You must doublequote the schema separately from the table name (though here it is optional as the schema is in lower case). As you have done it, is it as if `public.` is part of the table name, not the schema name

Comment: This is a pure SQL issue, not PostGIS-related, and better researched in [dba.se].

Answer (score 1):

SQL string literals require escape character rules - and your query does not honor them.

To the interpreter your query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  crosstab(
   'select town, rescode, proptype FROM "public.windhamCoParcels" WHERE rescode = '  -- string literal ends here
   C  -- non-SQL statement
   ' or rescode = '  -- another string literal
   S  -- another non-SQL statement
   ' or rescode = '  -- another string literal
   NS -- another non-SQL statement
   ' or rescode = '  -- another string literal
   T  -- another non-SQL statement
   ' order by 1,2'   -- another string literal
   ) AS Town(town_name text, Commercial text, in_state text, non_state text, town text);  -- at this time in this is just gibberish to the interpreter
```

If your SQL contains special characters - or as a general good practice, even - you want to format string literals using *dollar-quotes* (`$$`):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  CROSSTAB(
    $$
    SELECT
      town, rescode, proptype
    FROM
      public."windhamCoParcels"
    WHERE
      rescode IN ('C', 'S', 'NS', 'T')
    ORDER BY
      1,2
    $$
  ) AS "Town"(
    town_name TEXT,
    "Commercial" TEXT,
    in_state TEXT,
    non_state TEXT,
    town TEXT
);
```

Note that

- `"public.windhamCoParcels"` ***is not equal to*** `public."windhamCoParcels"` - the latter is schema qualified, the former only a strange table name
- `"Town"` ***is not equal to*** `Town`, but `Town` ***is equal to*** `town`!
- likewise, `"Commercial"` ***is not equal to*** `Commercial` **is equal to** `commercial`!

*Make sure you get a good understanding of identifier quoting in PostgreSQL! Look up how to format string literals if you are using them more frequent!*

Comment: Thanks but that gives me this: returned 0 [ERROR:  invalid return type
DETAIL:  SQL rowid datatype does not match return rowid datatype.
]

Comment: That is a problem unrelated to the error you asked for - you will have to make sure the column types that you define as the function result match those of the input columns.